# Debug simple shell script gives me 1064 error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql -u ***** -p***** admin-wp <<EOFMYSQL
DELETE FROM wp_8_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > 30
ORDER BY post_date
LIMIT 0, 10 
EOFMYSQL
```

gives me ERROR 1064 (42000) at line1: You have an error in your SQL sytax;

Comment: Can you give what your syntax error?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line1: You have an error in your SQL sytax; check the manual that corresponds to your mySQL syntax version for the right syntax to use near ' 10' at line 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with LIMIT 10 instead of given Offset to 0 ,10 like following you query you have to  use

```
DELETE FROM wp_8_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > 30
ORDER BY post_date
LIMIT 10
```

Check [**Manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html)

Answer (score -2):

On mysql you can execute the script like below, put your script in one file say myquries.sql and then execute

**Note: you are missing semicolon at the end of your query**
**Limit clause is incorrect in your query**... it should be as per below syntax...just put row_count to be deleted

```
 DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
 [WHERE where_condition]
 [ORDER BY ...]
 [LIMIT row_count]

 mysql -u ***** -p***** admin-wp < myquries.sql
```

Your syntax also works...just check if your query is good.

```
 $ cat t.sh
 mysql -u ***** -p****** <<EOFMYSQL
 select now();
 EOFMYSQL

 $ sh t.sh
 now()
 2014-08-07 23:49:56
```

Comment: did you try the syntax I gave?

Comment: yes. I am trying to write a shell script. not inputting at command line.

Comment: execute your query outside the script and see if its working fine ?

Comment: @narenda what is row_count, and how do you set it?

Comment: In your query ..you are writing limit 0,10 it should be limit 10 (i.e you want to delete only 10 rows). You have additional 0 which is incorrect as per syntax.